# Meteor CFS is limiting the Number of Files it's Displaying

Tags: javascript, meteor, collectionfs

I have no idea why it's doing it like this, but I'm using CollectionFS for Meteor, and I have an image uploader and on the page it's displaying the files that are uploaded and it's only displaying around 30 files at a time. I have no idea where this number comes from but each time when I upload a new file it pushes away one of the older ones. Also, I have an if helper block that separates image files from other types so that they can display differently, but it always displays the other files types first, then the images after, instead of just in the order they are uploaded. It also only shows about 7 and the rest are images. Sometimes when I add a new file, it randomly removes one of the others no matter how many have been uploaded. I am not sure why this is the case, but here is my code:

My HTML file

```
   {{#each images}}
       {{#if isImage}}
       <a href="#case-image-modal" role="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#case-image-modal" data-url="{{this.url}}">
          <img src="{{this.url uploading='/images/uploading.gif' storing='/images/uploading.gif'}}" class="case-image" alt="Case Image">
       </a>
       {{else}}
           <div class="case-file-name-wrapper">
               <p class="case-file-name"><a href="{{this.url download=true}}" title="{{this.name}}" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-file{{fileType this.type}}-o fa-4x"></i><br><span class="case-pdf-title">{{this.name}}</span></a></p>
           </div>
       {{/if}}
   {{/each}}
```

Event for insertion

```
"change .case-files-input": function(event, template) {

   var caseId = $(".hidden-case-id").val();

   FS.Utility.eachFile(event, function(file) {

     var newFile = new FS.File(file);
     newFile.metadata = {
        userId: Meteor.userId(),
        caseId: caseId,
        createdAt: new Date()
     };

     CaseImages.insert(newFile, function (err, fileObj) {
        if (!err) {
           console.log("Image Inserted successfully!");
        } else {
           console.log("ERROR inserting Case Image: " + err.reason);
        }

     });
   });
}
```

My helper

```
images: function () {
  var files = CaseImages.find({
     'metadata.caseId': this._id
  }, {
     sort: {
        uploadedAt: -1
     },
     limit: 100 // (I set this to 100 because
               //I thought it might override whatever limit is taking place??)
                // Just testing....it didn't help :(
  });

  //console.log(files.fetch());
  return files;

}
```

My collection.js

```
var imageStore = new FS.Store.GridFS("images", {
  mongoOptions: {},
  maxTries: 3,
  chunkSize: 1024*1024
});

CaseImages = new FS.Collection("case_images", {
 stores: [
    imageStore
 ],
 filter: {
   maxSize: 1024*1024*6, // in bytes
   allow: {
  extensions: ['png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'pdf', 'txt', 'bmp', 'docx', 'xlsx']
   }
 }
});

if (Meteor.isServer) {

 FS.debug = true;

 CaseImages.allow({
    insert:function(userId,doc){
      return true;
    },
    update:function(userId,doc,fields,modifier){
      return true;
    },
    remove:function(userId,doc){
      return true;
    },
    download:function(){
      return true;
    }
 });
}
```

I'm not sure if my code is even needed at all for this issue. Because I am not sure that it is some default behavior of CFS. Could anyone spot my problem or explain to me why it behaves like I described? I cannot seem to fix it.

Comment: Would you mind posting the image publication?

Comment: if you run a `CaseImages.find().count()` on the console what did you get?

Comment: @Julien Meteor.publish('case_images', function () {
   return CaseImages.find();
});

Comment: @Ethaan I get the correct/actual amount of files that were uploaded if I run CaseImages.find().count()

Comment: That's really strange, I don't see anything that could go wrong! Some things I'd try if I were you: remove the "if isImage" part, remove all the CaseImages.find({...}) options (remove everything, then if it works, add one after one), check if the metadata is properly set...

Comment: @Julien Wow! When I remove the {{isImage}} part, everything works fine!! That was supposed to be a built in feature for CFS to use that helper...I am either using it wrong, it's deprecated or it's buggy. I will build my own work around. Thanks.

Comment: Well now that I know that is part of the problem, I can't even build my own work around because my work around has the same results. If I remove the sort and metadata filter from my helper, and just do CaseImages.find({}), it does not loop through any files that are not images. There is something seriously wrong here, I'll need to keep digging I guess.

Comment: Ok, sry to comment 3 times. But I think you may be right about checking the metadata... I'm thinking it may have something to do with that. How can I check my metadata?

Comment: If its published, you should see it CaseImages.find(). If not, you can log in to Mongodb: "meteor mongo" in the terminal and "db.CaseImages.find()"

Comment: @Julien the metadata seems to be in there just fine in the console, and btw when I check it in Mongo it shows nothing, but I thought that's normal bc the data is stored in a different CFS collection